# Porting iPhone app to iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iphone only app that I need to port to iPad.  Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to do this (documentation, web, anything).

I know there are some great tutorials out there... but everything I am seeing is over 3 years old.  I am wondering if they still apply?

Thank You!

Comment: Here's a pretty [recent answer][1] that should help you out.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630498/convert-xcode-4-6-iphone-app-in-to-universal-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things you will want to consider:

1) If you are porting an iPhone app to iPad now, then you are most certainly moving from iOS 6 to 7. Make sure you understand the implications of that first, a great place to start is the "Upgrading your app to ios7" in the developer portal. It may not be titled that exactly, but it's close.

2) Assests. You will more than likely need to resize your images in photoshop (or your preferred image editing software) to accommodate a larger screen. If you are drawing assests in code and using **auto layout**, you will have minimal tweaking there.

3) It really comes down to nailing down your GUI for more screen real estate. This is a loaded statement, but it means everything from considering different design paradigms (for instance, using the UIPopover) that aren't used on an iPhone to creating entirely different controls to accomplish the same tasks. Usually, you'll find that you can do more with the large real estate.

In the end, I don't like to use the word "port" when moving an app from iOS to iPad. Given the nature of the device, you have a chance to - if anything - expand upon the capabilities of your existing app. *Use it*. I would highly consider just taking your business objects and go from there.

Hope this helps.